# Range.MergeCells property not updating

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a function which checks if a cell is part of a larger merged cell.

```
Function isMerged(rng As Range)
    isMerged = rng.MergeCells
End Function
```

And if you try using `isMerged(A1)` in `B1`, it correctly displays `FALSE`.
However, if you now merge `A1` with another cell, I would want the formula to automatically change to `TRUE` but it does not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can use a `Worksheet_Change` event in combination with [Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(method))?

Comment: Do some reading on Application.Volatile - this may be what you're after

Comment: Some good information [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1261444/custom-formula-not-updating)

Comment: Good thinking with `Application.Volatile` but, unfortunately, it won't work in this case. Such action will be triggered only when any cell in any workbook in the application window changes value. Merge/unmerge (is that a word? :)) is not a change in cell's value.